# Node.JS Error in uploading file to google drive

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I am a beginner in Node JS and I want to upload a local file to google drive. I have followed the instructions from this [URL](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs). But when I am going to run it, It gives an error like "insufficient permissions." Please help me out what I am missing in it.

Here is my code.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2Client = google.auth.OAuth2;
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.files.create',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'credentials.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', (err, content) => {
   if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
   // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
   authorize(JSON.parse(content), real_upload_files);
});

function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

   // Check if we have previously stored a token.
   fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);});
}

function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
      access_type: 'offline',
      scope: SCOPES,
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout,
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
      rl.close();
      oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
 });
}

function real_upload_files(auth) {
  var drive = google.drive('v3');
  var fileMetadata = {
     'name': 'Studentdata.xlsx',
     'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
  };
  var media = {
      mimeType: 'text/csv',
      body: fs.createReadStream('files/students.xlsx')
  };
  drive.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media: media,
        auth: auth,
        fields: 'id',
     }, function(err, file) {
     if (err) {
       console.log(err);
     } else {
       console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
     } 
  });
}
```

Please help me out what I am missing in it. Looking forward.

Comment: As the error says, you don't have enough permissions to upload files on the drive. Check your credentials and the permissions to see if you can can upload file

Comment: @Dimitri, Yes I have checked it. Credentials are also correct.

Comment: Check the permissions associated with the credentials.

Comment: How can we check that?

Comment: Did you try to look at the google console ?

Comment: Yes, It is already set up.

Comment: With the correct permissions ?

Comment: Yes, with correct permission.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that you're following the NodeJS Quickstart which uses the drive.files.list method which only uses the default 'read-only' scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
```

Now you modified the sample and decided to use upload method using [files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create#auth). Your default scopes won't work anymore because it's for 'read-only' (you're doing a 'write' command).  You need to use the scopes mentioned in the files.create method, at least one of these:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

After that, delete your previously saved credentials (somewhere in your directory where credentials are stored) for this project and re-do the authorization. This should work after that.